# Fill in missing values in R based on previous apperances

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(112)
round<-rep(1:5,4)
player<-rep(1:2, c(10,10))
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(5,5)),2)
age<-rep(NA,20)
age[1]<-26
age[11]<-32
gender<-rep(NA,20)
gender[1]<-"M"
gender[11]<-"F"
gamematrix<-cbind(player,game,round,age,gender)
gamematrix<-data.frame(gamematrix)

   player game round decs  age gender
1       1    1     1    2   26      M
2       1    1     2    3 <NA>   <NA>
3       1    1     3    3 <NA>   <NA>
4       1    1     4    3 <NA>   <NA>
5       1    1     5    1 <NA>   <NA>
6       1    2     1    1 <NA>   <NA>
7       1    2     2    1 <NA>   <NA>
8       1    2     3    3 <NA>   <NA>
9       1    2     4    1 <NA>   <NA>
10      1    2     5    2 <NA>   <NA>
11      2    1     1    1   32      F
12      2    1     2    2 <NA>   <NA>
13      2    1     3    3 <NA>   <NA>
14      2    1     4    2 <NA>   <NA>
15      2    1     5    3 <NA>   <NA>
16      2    2     1    3 <NA>   <NA>
17      2    2     2    2 <NA>   <NA>
18      2    2     3    2 <NA>   <NA>
19      2    2     4    3 <NA>   <NA>
20      2    2     5    2 <NA>   <NA>
```

In the actual data there are no "NA's" just empty cells - but I was unable to reproduce it.

Now, I want to fill the age and gender to all the missing rows, so that for the same player there will be the same age (gender) in all rows:

```
      player game round age gender
1       1    1     1  26      M
2       1    1     2  26      M
3       1    1     3  26      M
4       1    1     4  26      M
5       1    1     5  26      M
6       1    2     1  26      M
7       1    2     2  26      M
8       1    2     3  26      M
9       1    2     4  26      M
10      1    2     5  26      M
11      2    1     1  32      F
12      2    1     2  32      F
13      2    1     3  32      F
14      2    1     4  32      F
15      2    1     5  32      F
16      2    2     1  32      F
17      2    2     2  32      F
18      2    2     3  32      F
19      2    2     4  32      F
20      2    2     5  32      F
```

I know how to do it using a "for" function, but I am looking for a more elegant solution. I think there should be a way using "dplyr" - but I was not able to produce it. Any ideas?

Comment: See `?nafill` in data.table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next `tidyverse` approach with `fill()` function:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(112)
#Data
round<-rep(1:5,4)
player<-rep(1:2, c(10,10))
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(5,5)),2)
age<-rep(NA,20)
age[1]<-26
age[11]<-32
gender<-rep(NA,20)
gender[1]<-"M"
gender[11]<-"F"
gamematrix<-cbind(player,game,round,age,gender)
gamematrix<-data.frame(gamematrix)
#Now fill
gamematrix %>% group_by(player) %>% fill(age) %>% fill(gender)
```

Output:

```
player game round age gender
1       1    1     1  26      M
2       1    1     2  26      M
3       1    1     3  26      M
4       1    1     4  26      M
5       1    1     5  26      M
6       1    2     1  26      M
7       1    2     2  26      M
8       1    2     3  26      M
9       1    2     4  26      M
10      1    2     5  26      M
11      2    1     1  32      F
12      2    1     2  32      F
13      2    1     3  32      F
14      2    1     4  32      F
15      2    1     5  32      F
16      2    2     1  32      F
17      2    2     2  32      F
18      2    2     3  32      F
19      2    2     4  32      F
20      2    2     5  32      F
```

Also `gamematrix %>% group_by(player) %>% fill(c(age,gender))` can help to avoid multiple times the use of the same function producing equal results.

Comment: Thanks!! Will the same function help if the "age" appeared for each participant in the last row - i.e., last  round (rather than the first one)?

Comment: @YefR In that case you would have to use `fill(age,.direction = 'up')`